# How can we run selenium scripts written in python using jmeter?

Tags: python, jmeter

I am new to jmeter. I have selenium scripts written in python. I want to run these scrips using jmeter. Is their a way with the help of which we integrate python with jmeter.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JMeter plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/) for this. Use WebDriver Set.
Here is the article [how to use it](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler)